# Screen going black for ~1 second at random occasions and frequency

Tags: windows-10, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

My Laptop (MSI Prestige 15 A11SCS) has both, integrated (Intel) and dedicated (NVidia) graphics hardware.

When running Windows 10, the built-in monitor sometimes goes black for about a second, then the image comes back. I cannot see any pattern as to in what situations it's happening; it seem completely random. When it happens, the black-outs usually repeat several times with random pauses in-between (usually a few seconds). Sometimes the problem doesn't occur for minutes or even hours.

The problem is restricted to the built-it display, it never happens when an external one is connected, neiter via HDMI nor USB-C.

Things I tried:

- Windows and all drivers are up-to-date. I once updated the BIOS firmware back in ~2021 if I remember correctly.
- I tried enabling "Hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling" in Windows Settings, but no difference in behavior.
- External factors like temparature, or angle of the laptop lid seem to have no effect.
- I also tried disabling all sorts of power saving modes, e.g. in the Intel Graphics Command Center.

I'm a bit lost on how to even investigate the root cause of this. What could be causing these symptoms? And what can I do to further debug the issue?